# How can I loop through an array from my redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a store with

```
const initialState = {
    users: dummyData,
    is_created: false
};
```

where `users` is an array. Then a `getUsers` selector `const getUsers = state => state.users;`

Inside the component I used the `useSelector` to get access to my state.

```
    const { users } = useSelector(state => ({
        users: getUsers(state),
    }));
```

When I try to loop through `users`

```
        for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            //...
        }
```

I get an error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: What is the output if you console.log(users)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error from the redux dev tools chart. I am using combineReducers() and I named the reducer after the `users` the component name ie

```
export default combineReducers({
    users: users.reducers,
});
```

So the correct selector would be

```
const getUsers = state => state['users'].users;
```

Answer (score 0):

`useSelector` seems to run provided function at arbitrary time so its no guaranteed to have `users` defined when you want because of the `async` nature of it.

Couple ways you can tackle this:

First define default for `users` like:

```
   const { users = [] } = useSelector(state => ({
        users: getUsers(state),
    }));
```

That should resolve your issue.

Enhancement to your above code using `for` loop would be not to rely on `for` loop instead use `.map` like below:

```
   users.map(user => { ... });
```

Comment: The error is gone still it does not loop through. I tried a map first, I will try again still

Comment: can you post more of your code so that I can see how its crafted in order to get full context of it